# Type mismatch error (Scala)

Tags: java, scala

```
case class Item(val brand: String, val count: Int)

class Inventory {
  def add(amount:Int, item: Item): Item = {
    if(amount>0)    
    item.copy(count = item.count+amount)     
  }

  def subtract(amount:Int, item: Item): Item = {
    if(amount>0)
    item.copy(count = item.count-amount)
  }
}
```

How would one add if else statements to this code so that the amount must be greater than 0? When I add an if statement I get a type mismatch error.

Comment: Aside (which is very unimportant compared to using an `if` **without** an `else`)- you should properly indent your `if-statements` - to make it readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your the function doesn't always return, functions always have to return single value. What happens when `amount` is not greater that zero? I suppose you need to return `item` as it is. We fix it by adding an else statement.

```
def add(amount:Int, item: Item): Item = {
if(amount>0)    
  item.copy(count = item.count+amount)
else
  item     
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`if` is an expression in scala so it evaluates to something. If you don't put else compiler will put there `()` for you which is of type `Unit`. This will make your expression return `Unit` or `Item`. Their common supertype is `Any` so type of this expression is effectively `Any` while expected type is `Item`

```
def add(amount: Int, item: Item): Item = {
  if(amount > 0)    
    item.copy(count = item.count + amount)     
}
```

If you want to require the amount to be greater than zero just check it and throw exception if it's not. You can use builtin `require` for this.

```
def add(amount: Int, item: Item): Item = {
  require(amount > 0)    
  item.copy(count = item.count + amount)     
}
```

or you can handle this silently and don't modify item if wrong argument is passed

```
def add(amount: Int, item: Item): Item = {
  if(amount > 0)    
    item.copy(count = item.count + amount)
  else
    item
}
```

By the way you don't need vals in case class, it will be `val` anyway. This is how it should be:

```
case class Item(brand: String, count: Int)
```